# Microsound/Fourier/Granular Synthesis

Tags: granular-synthesis, microsound, learning

Hi all,

So, I've been watching this lecture on microsound given by Barry Truax.

[vimeo]7122776[/vimeo]

I'm inruiged, enthralled, fascinated, and pretty much every kind of -ed by it.  I understand far less of what he's talking about than I'd like to.  I'm also realizing how much more there is to this whole game than I previously thought.  From what I gather in order to really get what he's talking about I'll need a much better understanding of granular synthesis and Fourier theorem.  Both are frighteningly interesting and seem intimidatingly complex from where I sit.

The [Granular Synthesis page at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granular_synthesis) is a nice intro, but is nowhere near as detailed as I'd like.  What are some good references for the uninitiated? Has anyone studied this in depth and know of any books/websites designed for the layman?  The simpler the starting point the better.

Comment: Barry TRUAX. You spelled his name wrong. ;)

Comment: @Joel, So I did.  Apologies to all offended.

Comment: @Joel, @g.a.harry, Don't worry, I'm on it.

Comment: No offense, I just like names. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a huge and interesting subject but I bet you'll want to become familiar with Curtis Roads and his books before too long.

Start with this series of videos and then get his book 'Microsound' and 'Computer Music Tutorial': [link text](http://www.synthtopia.com/content/2009/05/12/secrets-granular-synthesis-curtis-roads/)

Also, from one of Barry Truax's own pages: [link text](http://www.sfu.ca/~truax/mviva.html)

Comment: Thanks!  This is perfect.  I'll see if I can find those books too.

Answer (score 1):

I second cebec. I own both books and are one of my best readings. Microsounds is very fascinating and useful to learn concepts of granular synthesis.

L.

p.s.: cebec, are you the same of electro-music? :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Luca! -- yes, that's me.

Here are two free standalone applications for Win/OSX that you can use to explore granular and pulsar synthesis. Max4Live versions are also available: [link text](http://www.densitygs.com/)

Comment: You are a magician.

Comment: OT: how small is this world :) i was Axiom on EM. very glad to see you here :)

Comment: OT: Indeed, it's smaller all the time! Glad to see a familiar face over here, as well!